# cannot run any eclipse commands to import or build project Code Composer Studio v9.0.0 from command line

Tags: code-composer

I am trying to set up a build environment for Code Composer Studio to build projects for the CC1352 Launchpad that I have with me, inside a docker container running ubuntu.

I was able to download and install Code Composer Studio version 9.0.0 (latest 10 - and I wasn't able to install the latest version through the command line). I was also able to install the Simplelink SDK which has software and examples for the dev-kit that I have.

I'm following this guide to import and build projects from the command line for Code Composer Studio: 
http://software-dl.ti.com/ccs/esd/documents/ccs_projects-command-line.html

However, when I try to import a project (com.ti.ccstudio.apps.projectImport) into a workspace, or just try to create a new project (com.ti.ccstudio.apps.projectCreate), or really run any kind of eclipse command, I get an error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "com.ti.ccstudio.apps.projectCreate" could not be found in the registry.`

The main command that I'm running in order to build this code is :

`./eclipse -noSplash -data "../../../ccs_workspaces/" -application com.ti.ccstudio.apps.projectCreate -ccs.name newProject -ccs.device com.ti.ccstudio.deviceModel.C6000.GenericC64xxDevice`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/algebratech/ccsv9-docker

Used this docker container. Can now create projects.